# How to render a polygon as a point feature?

Tags: openlayers-3

The [drawGeometry](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.render.canvas.Immediate.html) method will not apply a point style to a polygon.  That makes sense but I have a requirement that a polygon feature should be represented with both a stroke+fill style suitable for the feature as well as a point style, IMO, less-suitable for the feature.

For example:
[image: rendered parcel feature]

Using a combination of polygon and point feature styles:

```
[
 {
  "fill": {
   "pattern": {
    "orientation": "diagonal",
    "color": "rgba(230,113,26,1)",
    "spacing": 3,
    "repitition": "repeat"
   }
  }
 },
 {
  "circle": {
   "fill": { "color": "blue" },
   "opacity": 1,
   "stroke": {
    "color": "rgba(0,255,0,1)",
    "width": 1
   },
   "radius": 20
  }
 },
 {
  "image": {
   "anchor": [
    16,
    48
   ],
   "imgSize": [
    32,
    48
   ],
   "anchorXUnits": "pixels",
   "anchorYUnits": "pixels",
   "src": "http://openlayers.org/en/v3.17.1/examples/data/icon.png"
  }
 }
]
```

One solution I've come up with is to replace the drawGeometry to call both drawPolygon and drawPoint:

[image: drawGeometry code]

But it seems like support for rendering a polygon using a point styling should be supported some other way.  Maybe in the drawPolygon implementation it should detect a point style and react accordingly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the geometry option of a style object and then return the interior point with geometry.getInteriorPoint(), see: http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/polygon-styles.html?q=geometry+style for an example

Comment: That [worked](https://rawgit.com/ca0v/ol3-lab/master/rawgit.html?run=labs/style-viewer&geom=polygon&style=stroke/solid,icon/png,text/text&debug=1)!